# Can a Flutter module act as a plugin/package?

Tags: flutter

I have Flutter code I need to share with an existing iOS native application. For this I use a Flutter module and am able to get it to work

Now, I have another app that is done purely in Flutter but I want to share the code that's in the Flutter module with the Flutter app

How can I achieve this? Basically what I'm hoping for is that the module can act like a plugin/package to the Flutter app. But if that doesn't work, should I move all shared code to a new Flutter plugin, then reference the plugin in the module, and also reference the plugin in the Flutter app?

So then under that, the module is essentially a wrapper around the plugin. The plugin is where the true code would live

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that a module can act as a plugin, and a plugin can act as a package. So therefore a module can act as a package too

So in short, I only need a module